# I have multiple dataframes under one name and I need to create a new column in each one by combining two of the other columns?

Tags: r, csv, multiple-columns

I am trying to take in a bunch of csv files of a specific name form (dates) as dataframes and then combine data from two of the columns into a new column for each of the files. There are over 100 of these files so I do not want to manually create a new column for each file. Is there any way to do this? Here is an example:

```
     a b      a b               a b  c      a b  c
   x 2 3    x 3 1     -->     x 2 3 23    x 3 1 31
```

And here is my current code:

```
     f <- list.files(pattern="201\\d{5}\\.csv")
     mydata <- sapply(f, read.csv, simplify=FALSE)
     mydata$c <- paste(mydata$a,mydata$b)
```